# nelmio/alice random string with specified long

Tags: symfony, random, fixtures, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I was trying to find way generate random unique string with 8 characters long using nelmio/alice.

And I've found only **`<uuid()>`** (`token (unique): <uuid()>`)method, unfortunately it returns too long string, I need just 8 characters.

May be some one knows elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks I've found solution

```
token (unique): '<( substr( md5( uniqid( rand(), true ) ) , 0, 8) )>'
```

Answer (score 1):

[nelmio/alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) uses [fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) for data generation, you can use `Faker\Provider\Lorem` or `Faker\Provider\en_US\Text`:

```
<sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true)>
<text($maxNbChars = 200)>
<realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2)>
```